# How to perform actions in order in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on a simple app that has only an image & a button. When the button is pressed a sound will play and a  web page will open. I want the sound to play first before opening the web page. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func webButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let Bismillah = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Basmalah", ofType: "mp3")!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Bismillah as URL)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {
        print("Problem in getting File")
    }
    audioPlayer.play()


    if let url = URL(string: "http:/donate.edialoguec.com/campaign/details/63") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an event of `itemDidFinishPlaying:` and open the web page here. In your case if sound file is large it would not be play because you're opening the URL outside the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
audioPlayer.play()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
   if let url = URL(string: "http:/donate.edialoguec.com/campaign/details/63")  {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
   }
 }
```

Comment: You could maybe also check the method `prepareToPlay()` and combine it with this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just to tell you @SulaimanAlammar, It will work if sound file is lesser than 1 second.

Comment: @TheTiger what about if he enabled background audio , Also form the OP's case it seems he want to play a ting as it's not logical to have a long audio and wait until it's finish playing more than 1 second then navigate , it's a button click that UX should be friendly , besides the op can get the duration directly and set it as a delay no need for delegates

Comment: @Sh_Khan First of all the comment was not for you. It was for OP. He should know why this code will work with a delay of 1 seconds and why not working without any delay while his code is correct. You didn't mention the reason in your answer as well. So he just copied this code and happy this worked but don't know why. So I just told him why it worked. No offense from myside!

Answer (score 0):

Using dispatch after would work if the delay time is >= the sound's duration.
To completely achieve your goal, you need to set `audioPlayer.delegate = self` and implement this method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying
When the player finished playing, that method will get called and you can open the web page at that point.